# How to detect whether a window is in focus?

Tags: x11, window, xdotool, focus

I'm not experienced in scripting but I've made this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# hint: use "xdotool getmouselocation" to get values

if xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname | grep -Eq " - LibreOffice Calc$"
  then 
    xdotool mousemove --sync 218 144 click 1
fi
```

The purpose is to have a keyboard shortcut to using the `sum` function in LibreOffice Calc 4.4.5. There is no default keyboard shortcut in LibreOffice Calc and it doesn't seem possible to assign one to the `sum` function: see [Bug 39302](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39302).

The shortcut executes `mousemove` *only* when a Calc window is in focus. Otherwise, it should do nothing. (The coordinates are specific to my usage.)

My question is this: is there a better way to check whether the Calc window is in focus?

[How do I change key bindings based on which window is focused?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197668/61798) seems related but doesn't have an answer.

Comment: Did you try this -https://gist.github.com/kui/2622504  .. it looks like a simple c routine to get active window. I have neither used nor tested it btw ...

Comment: If you're unsure about the results of `if` and `pipe`, run the subcommands alone first, then chain them. That is `xdotool ...`. Then `xdotool ... | grep ... ; echo $?`. Then `if ... then`. You also can run the script with `sh -x script`.